# The report cannot be displayed. (rsprocessingaborted) in CRM 2016

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, reporting, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2016

[image]I Finished my report on Visual studio 2015 and working normally on it but after deployment it on CRM 2016 I found this error (The report cannot be displayed. (rsProcessingAborted) ) In my Data source I connect to server and my database Erphistory so any help??

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is one of the useless error message CRM produces.

If its CRM online, all you can do is troubleshooting using [this technique](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/posts/how-to-debug-rsprocessingaborted-report-error).

> Steps to debug ‘rsProcessingAborted’ error:
>
> Download the RDL of the report
>   Open the downloaded RDL in the Visual Studio Shell (Integrated)
>   And then after entering the valid credentials, click preview and Voila!

The resulting error description will be more than enough for us to resolve the issue.

If its on-premise you got a lot to do [for investigation](http://blog.simpletrees.com/2013/04/mscrm-and-dreaded-rsprocessingaborted.html) & fixing the issue.

> A problem within the report or a sub report.
>   Problems with Data Sources set on the reports
>   Reporting Extensions not installed on the report server
>   SSRS Logon context not having adequate rights
>   CRM App Pool running under a user context and not configured correctly